# Convert object keys to zod schema

Tags: arrays, typescript, key, schema, zod

Suppose I have this json object:

```
const amenities = { "wifi": "Wifi", "tv": "Tv", "steamIron": "Steam iron", "kitchenette": "Kitchenette", "fridge": "Fridge", "airConditioner": "Air conditioner", "fan": "Fan", "gym": "Gym", "pool": "Pool", "parking": "Parking", "lounge": "Lounge", "laundry": "Laundry", "stove": "Stove", "balcony": "Balcony", "microwave": "Microwave", "oven": "Oven", "desk": "Desk", "towels": "Towels", "bedSheets": "Bed sheets", "studyRoom": "Study room", "chair": "Chair", "table": "Table", "elevator": "Elevator", "generator": "Generator", "security": "Security", "cafe": "Cafe", "restaurant": "Restaurant", "housekeeping": "Housekeeping" }
```

and I want to create a zod schema that does the same thing as this:

```
interface Amenities extends Record<keyof typeof amenities, boolean> {}
```

The result would be something like this:

```
const a: amenities = { wifi: false, tv: true, ... }
```

How can I do that without redefining the keys?

I tried this:

```
export const Amenities = z.record(z.boolean()).refine((val) => {
    const keys = Object.keys(amenities);
    for (const key of keys) {
        if (!(key in val)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}, {
    message: 'Amenities should have all keys defined',
}).nonstrict();
```

However, when inferring the type and creating an object with that type, it does not seem to suggest the fields to be defined.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const Amenities = z.record(
  z.custom<keyof typeof amenities>((data) => {
    return typeof data === "string" && data in amenities;
  }),
  z.boolean()
);
```